# implicitly specializing template class without the use of <>

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection

I am extracting dependencies from a codebase using templates. In doing so the new classes are template classes now. I want to initialise them just like before. Otherwise I would have to touch parts of my production code before I have tests in place.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//OLD SOURCE
class LogUser_Old
{
public:
    void print() { cout << "LogUser Old" << endl; }
};

//NEW SOURCE
struct normal 
{
    static void log(const char * out) { cout << out << endl; }
};

struct injected
{
    static void log(const char * out) { cout << "injected '" << out << "'" << endl; }
};

template< typename output = normal>
class LogUser_New
{
public:
    void print() { output::log("LogUser New"); }
};

int main()
{
    //OLD Production Code
    LogUser_Old lo;
    lo.print();
    //New Production Code
    LogUser_New<> ln; //THE <> is a change in Production code
    ln.print();
    //Testcode
    LogUser_New<injected> ln_silent;
    ln_silent.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Here `LogUser` was rewritten to be injectable. `_Old` marks the old state `_New` marks the new state. The previous Production code used to instantiate the class has to be updated from `LogUser user;` to `LogUser<> user;`.

Is there a way to make the compiler implicitly figure out that he can use the empty template case here so the production code can remain just the same as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `typedef`:

```
template< typename output = normal>
class LogUser_New_tmpl
{
public:
    void print() { output::log("LogUser New"); }
};

typedef LogUser_New_tmpl<> LogUser_New;
```

If you have C++11, you can of course use `using` instead of `typedef`:

```
using LogUser_New = LogUser_New_tmpl<>;
```

Comment: @zenith Certainly, will amend answer.